# recursively find max file or sub-directory in an HDFS folder

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I want to recursively find max file or sub-directory in an HDFS folder. Is there any command or script to refer to?

thanks in advance,
Lin

Comment: What do you mean by "max"?  The largest file?  The last file lexographically ordered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this shell script, if you want to find the file with max size:

```
h1out="/path/to/out/file/hadoop-ls-out.txt"
a1out="/path/to/out/file/hadoop-awk-out.txt"
h1="`hadoop fs -lsr /usr > $h1out`"
a1="`awk '{print $5,$8}' $h1out > $a1out`"
a2="`awk 'BEGIN{first=1;}{if (first) { max = min = $1; first = 0; next;}if (max < $1) max=$1; if (min > $1) min=$1; }END { print max }' $a1out`"
g1="`grep -r $a2 $a1out`"
echo $g1
```

**EXPLANATION:**

`h1out` is the file path to store **hadoop fs -lsr** output

`a1out` is the file path to store **awk** output

`h1` lists files recursively in my HDFS path at `/usr` and the stores it in `h1out`

`a1` prints the **filesize** and **filename** (with full path) from `h1out` file and saves it in `a1out` file

`a2` finds **min** and **max** values from **filesize**, but i used only max (since you needed max) so it displays only max filesize

`g1` searches for the value of `$a2` in file `a1out` and prints it. This result prints the **filesize** and **filename** with **max fileseize**.

> **NOTE:** If you are using latest hadoop version, replace "**hadoop fs**" with "**hdfs dfs**"